# top.close() does not work in Firefox when called from a frame in a frameset

Tags: firefox, frameset

I have a popup window that contains a frameset. I have a "Close" button in one of the frames that class "top.close()" to close the opopup window.
It works in IE but in Firefox you get an error "top.close is not a function".

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to see your markup, but chances are either `top` is something you're not expecting or your frameset has a frame named "close" and you're running into the weird IE behavior where `top.close` is a Window but `top.close()` calls some function named `close` in the toplevel window.

Comment: Thanks a lot.In fact I realized this after I posted and I intended

Comment: I intended to post it but I see you already have figured it out :-)